# How to parse steam api JSON and print it out? PHP

Tags: php, json, api, steam

I want to parse JSON that I recieve from steam via api link http://steamcommunity.com/id/theorangeass/inventory/json/753/1/ , but when I try to print it with echo it show nothing.
Here is the code

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/theorangeass/inventory/json/753/1/');
$json = json_decode($data, true);

echo $json->success;
```

var_dump:

```
array(6) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["rgInventory"]=> array(1) { ["922506184369981039"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(18) "922506184369981039" ["classid"]=> string(10) "1254492673" ["instanceid"]=> string(10) "2070301907" ["amount"]=> string(1) "1" ["pos"]=> int(1) } } ["rgCurrency"]=> array(0) { } ["rgDescriptions"]=> array(1) { ["1254492673_2070301907"]=> array(18) { ["appid"]=> string(3) "753" ["classid"]=> string(10) "1254492673" ["instanceid"]=> string(10) "2070301907" ["icon_url"]=> string(116) "U8721VM9p9C2v1o6cKJ4qEnGqnE7IoTQgZI-VTdwyTBeimAcIowbqB-harb00cJ0fNdiCJoFB3O541FNc9ZPYXYjjL7UqfFEwOtgZKcs0eWlClqzSJn6" ["icon_url_large"]=> string(106) "U8721VM9p9C2v1o6cKJ4qEnGqnE7IoTQgZI-VTdwyTBeimAcIowbqB-harb00cJ0fNdiA54UEGOnqGQPJ9hDZHA50feEo7RMyO_GQNzkkA" ["icon_drag_url"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(4) "BEEP" ["market_name"]=> string(0) "" ["name_color"]=> string(0) "" ["background_color"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(4) "Gift" ["tradable"]=> int(0) ["marketable"]=> int(0) ["commodity"]=> int(0) ["cache_expiration"]=> string(20) "2017-01-02T00:00:00Z" ["fraudwarnings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(223) "This is a restricted gift which can only be redeemed in these countries: Armenia, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Georgia, Kyrgyzstan, Kazakhstan, Moldova, Republic of, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, Ukraine, Russian Federation" } ["descriptions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(216) "A combination of Yoshi’s Island-style platforming with a gravity gun right out of Half-Life, BEEP is an amazing physics-platformer. Despite its friendly art style, this is a hardcore platformer in the truest sense." } } ["actions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(13) "View in store" ["link"]=> string(41) "http://store.steampowered.com/app/104200/" } } } } ["more"]=> bool(false) ["more_start"]=> bool(false) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to echo a `boolean`. If you are wanting to echo `true` you're going to need to do an if, or a switch statement. An if statement would probably be easiest.

```
echo $json->success == true ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

To parse the array to retrieve the item id's in the rgInventory to must do a foreach.

```
foreach ($json['rgInventory'] as $item) {
    echo $item['id'];
}
```

Where you should start learning about arrays is [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thank you very much! Btw can you explain me how to print out "id" wich is in rgInventory->922506184369981039->id?

Comment: What you are trying to do is parse an array, not json. It's received as json then `json_decode` turns it into an array. I have updated the answer to fit your comment.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Appreciate it!